# FineUploader: Track Scaled Images ClientSide

Tags: javascript, image, fine-uploader

We're using FineUploader to upload files to a REST service. The current version of FineUploader allows for automatic upload of scaled images [as detailed here](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/scaling.html).

FineUploader has ways to track scaled images in relation to their original image on the Server side. How do we track scaled images on the client side after successfully uploading an image?

- Having the server determine what is/isn't a scaled image is not an option, this has to all be handled on the client.
- FineUploader allows text to be appended to the end of scaled file names, however I don't want to use string matching as a mechanism to determine whether or not an image is scaled or not.

Comment: The scaled versions are not generated until the moment before the file is uploaded.  What do you intend to do with the information you are seeking client-side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate the responses but I was able to find the answer by looking at the [FineUploader API](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/methods.html#getParentId).

It looks like the getParentId method is exactly what I was looking for.

> getParentId (scaledFileId)
>
> Get the ID of the parent file for this scaled file.
>
> Parameters:
>
> Integer id The ID of a scaled image file
>
> Returns:Integer Returns the ID of the scaled image's parent file.
>   `null` if this is not a scaled image or a parent cannot be located.

Here is some psuedo-code showing how to track this on the client-side in a FineUploader callback:

```
callbacks: {
            onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJSON, xhr) {
                var isThumbnail = this.getParentId(id) !== null ? true : false;
            }
}
```

Comment: Your code will fail if the parent ID is 0.  That may not actually happen due to the way in which Fine Uploader orders scaled images in relation to the original, but it's probably not safe to assume that this will always be true.

Comment: Interesting, and I appreciate the input, I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Fine Uploader doesn't provide you with access to the scaled image `Blob`s via the API, just the original file.  The reason for this is described in the [scaling feature documentation page](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/scaling.html):

> Calls to the getFile API method will return the associated original
>   file, not the scaled version. This is due to the fact that, again, the
>   scaled version is not kept around any longer than necessary to
>   conserve memory. Also, generating a scaled version is an asynchronous
>   operation, which would require the getFile API method return a
>   promise, introducing a breaking change to the API.

If you'd like to manage the scaled versions of the files yourself, you can turn off the auto-scaling feature and generate scaled versions yourself via the [`scaleImage` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#scaleImage).  Scaled versions generated this way can be submitted for upload via the [`addBlobs` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#addBlobs) as well.

Comment: Would be nice if the dimensions of the scaled images could be exposed somewhere in the api.